# Why does the bind operator used with an incomplete lambda function work?

Tags: haskell

From Graham Hutton's 'programming haskell':

```
data Expr = Val Int | Div Expr Expr

safediv :: Int -> Int -> Maybe Int
safediv _ 0 = Nothing
safediv x y = Just (n `div` m)

{- |
(>>=) :: Maybe a -> (a -> Maybe b) -> Maybe b
mx >>= f = case mx of
             Nothing -> Nothing
             Just x -> f x
-}

eval :: Expr -> Maybe Int
eval (Val n)   = Just n
eval (Div x y) = eval x >>= \n ->
                 eval y >>= \m ->
                 safediv n m
```

I understand that currying is involved in the 'eval' function declaration. I have tried to reproduce this type in declaration in ghci with no success. For example

```
map (\x ->) [1..3]
```

What are then the usage boundaries of the incomplete lambda form declaration?

Comment: There's nothing "incomplete" here, to the right of the `=` is a single expression which just happens to have been split onto multiple lines. Because each line is indented the same amount it's understood by the compiler as if the line breaks weren't there.

Comment: Put another way, it is precisely *because* the lambda expression is not completed on one line that the parser knows the expression continues onto the next line. Whether or not the expression is continued *correctly* depends on the indentation provided.

Comment: great question. not for the Haskell programmers, but for the Haskell newbies. it's one of Haskell syntax quirks which often stumbles newcomers. mustn't be so, if only the implicit parens (and delimiters, in general) were shown explicitly. Lambda expressions are recognized by the rule of "maximal munch": "eat up" i.e. consume as much of the input as possible. IOW, the lambda expression is extended as much to the right, as possible. ignoring the whitespace. thus you end up with the nested lambdas, shown in the answer.

Answer (score 3):

As mentioned by @RobinZigmond, there is nothing incomplete. You are probably confused by the line breaks. You can write your `eval` function alternatively as:

```
eval (Div x y) = eval x >>= \n -> eval y >>= \m -> safediv n m
```

..and if you add parentheses it should be visible, that you simply have nested lambdas:

```
eval (Div x y) = (eval x) >>= (\n -> (eval y) >>= (\m -> safediv n m))
```